# PhoneGap- Save file when there isn't connection and save into a web server when connection is again avaiable

Tags: android, caching, cordova, offline-caching

I want to build an application in phonegap that takes notes and saves it in a server but when there isn't connection saves it locally and when the connection becomes available saves in the web server. How can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Cordova (phonegap) has a lot of API's that can help you do this, including:

- [Connection](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/cordova_connection_connection.md.html#Connection) - Would be useful to determine if the device is connected to a network or not. So in your save function, call this method to determine if you need to save to a server or save locally.
- [Storage](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage) - This is what you would use when the device is offline to store the notes data on the device.
- [Events](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#online) - You can use `addEventListener()` to listen for the 'online' event, which gets fired when the device connects to the Internet. Using this you would be able to automatically save the data back to the server without the user having to do anything.

You'll probably just want to send the notes via JSON to your server when the device is online and the user hits save.